# Random dependent variables using QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, r, qt, parallel-processing, statistics

I ran into a problem of design. Prepare, as there will be a lot to come, and perhaps it is a too complex problem for SO.

For people familiar with R this might help:
I created a package in R for creating correlations between variables (for the purpose of simulations). I created a multiple threads version to allow parallelism. While R makes it seem embarrassingly parallel, I almost reconsider this statement in C++.

- Sample a 100000 by 2 random data matrix.
- Split it into a list of (100,000 / 200) = 500 splits of 200 rows by 2 columns data matrices.
- Using a multi-core list apply function (`mclapply`, which can handle matrices as "item" in a list), I was able to send these smaller data matrices with 2 dimensions to the same function, though in different threads.
- The function *randomly* rearranged the first column conditionally on the second column to produce a certain correlation. It then returned the rearranged matrix. I am not asking for this part, I am just mentioning this to outrule solutions that skip steps by independently creating `x` and `y`.
- The list apply function automatically glues together these 500 splits of 200 rows by 2 columns into one big matrix (100,000 by 2).

> ```
> listdata:
>
>  [[1]] 
>   [1]  [2]
>   ...  ...
>   ...  ...
>  [[2]]
>   [1]  [2]
>   ...  ...
>   ...  ...
> ```

Applying:

```
mclapply(listdata, myFunction, cores=4)
```

Result:

```
  [1]   [2]
  ...   ...
  ...   ...
  ...   ...
  ...   ...
```

### Randomness

I want to have a thread-safe, statistically random (results unrelated to the pseudo randomness) function yielding aggregated dependent `x` and `y` vectors.

- Randomness is difficult since there usually is a global state for a random generator, which is not possible to share in a parallel situation.

Some of my solutions showed that the threads all used similar values, which does not happen using R.

### Qt

I am using Qt, and I am trying to use QtConcurrent for creating the right (convenient for user) amount of threads, given a variable amount of splits.

I'll first say that I did not find a way to be able to pass multiple arguments to a function in a QtConcurrent. They all seem to be focused on mapping, without allowing extra arguments.

One attempt was the following:

```
QList< QVector<double> > list_of_one_split;
QList< QList< QVector<double> > list_containing_all_splits;
QVector<double> vector_of_doubles(10);
qFill(vector_of_doubles.begin(), vector_of_doubles.end(), 1); // not random
list_of_a_split.append(vector_of_doubles); // x variable split
list_of_a_split.append(vector_of_doubles); // y variable split
list_containing_all_splits.append(list_of_a_split) // first split
list_containing_all_splits.append(list_of_a_split) // second split

QtFuture<void> res = `QtConcurrent::map(list_containing_all_splits.begin(), 
                                        list_containing_all_splits.end(), 
                                        mapFunction)`

QList< QVector<double> > mapFunction(QList< QVector<double> > &list_of_a_split) 
{
   // random arranging one column on other
   return list_of_a_split;
}
```

For some reason this return did not seem to affect the original list.

Another way I tried was to generate the `y` within the mapper function, giving it `X` as input, and returning `y` into a new variable using `QtConcurrent:mappedReduced()`, mapping over `x` in split form, producing `y`, return `y` split, and using reduce to merge it together into `QVector<double> y`. This has serious random issues, as I am not able to send a `generator` as extra argument.

I am just showing my efforts here, but feel free to approach the problem from any way (though same results) you like.

### The goal in the end:

```
// Whether or not packed in a QList< >:
QVector<double> x = {..., ..., ..., ...};
QVector<double> y = {..., ..., ..., ...}; // dependent on x
```

Comment: "Randomness is difficult since there usually is a global state for a random generator, which is not possible to share in a parallel situation." - I'm not sure this is the case, could you not use a QMutex?

Comment: @JamesElderfield Thanks for the reply. Two things. 1) I do not see how to fit in a QMutex into a QtConcurrent. 2) The rearranging within each split requires random numbers, and when there is a QMutex locking the situation, it essentially becomes serial rather than parallel to obtain random indices.

Comment: 1) This page (http://www.johanpaul.com/blog/2011/09/easy-threading-with-qtconcurrentrun/) has an example of using QMutex with QtConcurrent under "Practical hints". 2) I see what you mean about this causing it to become serial, what about generating a random list of numbers at the beginning and then using this list to set the seed for each thread's independent RNG? I believe this would still give you statistically random output (but I am not sure).

Comment: @JamesElderfield I have tried using the first element of the list squared (so it will be possible) as srand(pow(list[0][0], 2)), but this did not work. Also, how do you send this list to the function when it is only possible to send one type to the mapper, and then receive that same format back?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean for the first part but to send the list to the function I would write a wrapper class. This class would contain variables for a RNG state (initially from the list of random numbers), list_of_a_split and anything else you might need. Then you can call the mapFunction on this class.